# c# Core MVC cannot access non-static field

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Constructor services:

```
IUserService userService;
IUserRoleService userRoleService;
IModuleService moduleService;

public AuthorizeUserCheck(IUserService userService, IUserRoleService userRoleService, IModuleService moduleService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
    this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
    this.moduleService = moduleService;
}
```

Code

```
public static bool HasAccess(string controllerName, string actionName)
{
    var user = userService.Get();
    int moduleId = 0;
    var actions = actionName.Split(',');

    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        var module = moduleService.Get($"{controllerName}.{action}");

        if (module != null)
        {
            moduleId = module.Id;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (moduleId == 0)
        return false;
    if (userRoleService.GetUserRole(moduleId, user.Id))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

`userService.Get()` cannot access non-static field 
get static method error when adding services.

on the razor side when we delete the `static    bool isAllowedAuthorization =new AuthorizeUserCheck.HasAccess("Authorization", "AuthorizationList");` we're getting an error here

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You tried to access the non-static `useService` field from the static `HasAccess`. Remove the `static` keyword

Comment: what error do you get when you remove `static`?

Comment: error I receive when remove.
an object reference is required for the non-static field,method,or property(xxxx,xxxx)

Comment: You must have a `new AuthorizeUserCheck` somewhere in your code. This object is your required reference, that you prepend to your call to HasAccess.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says non-static field is getting accessed in the static method. Which means either you can change the method parameter to include `IUserRoleService userRoleService` or declare the variable as `static IUserRoleService userRoleService`. I would recommend passing it as a parameter.

```
public static bool HasAccess(string controllerName, string actionName, IUserRoleService userRoleService)
```

`public static bool HasAccess` is a commonly accessible method and not tied to any instance variable like `userRoleService`. So we cant expect this static method to access to an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` key word simply states that: "This class member will be the same for all instances (object) of this class, I will not duplicate it for each object". Therefore, it can not work with class members that can change with each instance you create (instance members).

Solution 1: mark the `IUserService userService;` field as static: (i.e) `static IUserService userService;`

Solution 2: make the method an instance method (non-static) by removing the static keyword from its definition: (i.e) `public bool HasAccess(string controllerName, string actionName)`.